# How to run formatter using command line in Android

Tags: android-studio, coding-style, reformatting

i want to sync Code Style in android project with team members.
i tried macro, but i often forgot it before commit.

is it possible to run "reformat code" using command line?
if yes, then how to exec reformat code when build using .gradle